# Codeigniter - Form validation callbacks

Tags: php, codeigniter, webforms

What is wrong with this code ?
The problem is that the is_empty method is called but is_image not.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'image', 'callback_is_empty|callback_is_image');
```

Here is the is_image method

```
public function is_image()
{
  echo 'Hello from is_image';
}
```

Comment: Are you using any specific Framework? The code above isn't really showing the code actually doing the business.

Comment: He is using the Codeigniter php framework

Comment: Use the built in logging functionality of CI instead of the echo statement. Also as stated by @Catfish the custom function MUST return true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom callback functions need to return "True" or "False".

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but have you tried to use

```
'callback_is_empty||callback_is_image'
```

instead of

```
'callback_is_empty|callback_is_image'
```

also have you read this:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks

Sorry I couldn't been more usefull.